# Fast way to create loops between existing vertices

Tags: modeling, loop

I have this mesh

[image]

I need to create loops between the selected vertices around the top of the part, keeping the spacing between the loops the same as the source vertices.

[image]

[image]

I know how to do this 1 at a time with several different methods, <kbd>ctrl-r</kbd>, knife tool, <kbd>g g</kbd>, etc, but this is time consuming and does not end up with "perfect" spacing.

***Is there a faster/better technique?***

This is the result I would like to find a faster technique for. This was done using <kbd>ctrl-r</kbd> scrolling wheel to the desired number of cuts, then 1-by-1 selecting a loop and <kbd>g g</kbd> until the loop lined up with a source vertex. Painful when there are many to do!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but have you tried selecting 2 vertices and pressing J?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes, J tries to take the shortest path, which is underneath, not over the top. I'll add a picture of the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate points, seperate points, extrude them and use knife project?

Comment: Hello :). This sounds like a neat solution, could you please add some images to illustrate the answer?

Comment: @Chrischan That's an interesting approach! Please add some detail of what you're thinking, some pics would be good

Comment: @Chrischan I gave it a shot! Brilliant solution! Please edit your answer with more info so others can find it, it's very worth sharing. Thanks!